# What happens when a favicon request is answered with a normal html response?

Tags: html, node.js, favicon

Any idea what happens when my Nodejs app returns a webpage on a favicon request? I don't have a way to simulate this but I see that my app continuously gets such requests and wonder if end users are getting the pages right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will just cause your page to have the default icon, nothing really bad. However, I think it'd be better style to respond with a 404.